# Knockout: Adding to observable Arrays in Nested ViewModels

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a few nested view models with observable arrays and am unable to successfully add to any of the nested arrays.  Adding at the top-level works fine.  I've done lots of reading and fiddling to try to troubleshoot what I'm doing wrong but to no avail.

The hierarchy is as follows:
Queue-->Files-->Claims-->Lines

I can add new files to a queue but I can't get new claims added (tried via File and via Queue)

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/bxfXd/254/

**UPDATE**: All answers below pointed me to the core issue - using raw data instead of instantiated models in my observable arrays.  updated fiddle with working code: http://jsfiddle.net/7cDmg/1/

**HTML**:

```html
<h2>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>        
    <a href='javascript:' data-bind="click: addFile">AddFile</a>
</h2>
<div data-bind="foreach: files">
    <h3>File: <span data-bind="text: name"></span> (<span data-bind="text: id"></span>)
    <a href='javascript:' data-bind="click: $data.addClaim">AddClaimViaFile</a>
    <a href='javascript:' data-bind="click: $root.addClaim">AddClaimViaQueue</a></h3> 

    <div data-bind='foreach: claims'>
        <h3 data-bind="text: ud"></h3> 
        <table border=1>
            <thead>
                <td>id</td>    <td>procedure</td>    <td>charge</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody  data-bind='foreach: lines'>
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: id"></td> 
                    <td data-bind="text: procedure"></td> 
                    <td data-bind="text: charge"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
var line1 = { id: 1, procedure: "Amputate", charge: 50 };
var line2 = { id: 2, procedure: "Bandage", charge: 10};
var claim1 = { ud: '1234E123', charge: 123.50, lines: [line1,line2] };
var claim2 = { ud: '1234E222', charge: 333.51, lines: [line2,line2] };
var file1 = { id: 1, name: "Test1.txt", claims: [claim2] };
var file2 = { id: 2, name: "Test2.txt", claims: [] };
var queue = { id: 1, name: "JoesQueue", files: [file1,file2] }; 


function Line(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.procedure = ko.observable(data.procedure);
    this.charge = ko.observable(data.charge);
}

function Claim(data) {
    this.ud = ko.observable(data.ud);
    this.charge = ko.observable(data.charge);
    this.lines = ko.observableArray(data.lines);
}

function File(data) {
    var self=this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.claims = ko.observableArray(data.claims);
    self.addClaim = function(file) {  //this never gets called.. Why?
        alert("File.addClaims");
       self.claims.push(claim1);
    }          
}

function Queue(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.files = ko.observableArray(data.files);
    this.addClaim = function(file) {
        alert("Queue.addClaim");
        console.log(file);
       file.claims.push(claim1); //This line gets hit, but no claims get added..Why?
    };     
    this.addFile = function() {
        alert("Queue.addFile");
        this.files.push(file2); //Works - adding seems to only work at the top level :(
    }
}

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new Queue(queue));
});
```

​

Comment: There are several errors here. First, your data is not structured hierarchically, you have it all in seperate, unrelated arrays. Second, at your 2nd to last comment, `file` is undefined. Third, you seem to want the `files` array on `Queue` to be an array of the type File, but to not construct it. You call `new Queue(queue)` to make a new `Queue` but do not do that same for Files or claims. Your arrays are all untyped.

Comment: Correct - the main issue was that I was using raw data in my observableArray's instead of constructing new models of the appropriate type.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quickly checked your jsfiddle and I see that there are a few problems like:

- the initial data you pass to `Queue()` constructor is not made of observables. In other words the initial `queue.files` observable array contains raw JS objects, and not instances of your `File` viewmodel.
- `data-bind="click: File.addClaim"` doesn't do what you want it to do. It should be `data-bind="click: addClaim"`, but first your `queue.files` array has to consist of `File` instances.

I fixed those problems in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ntXJJ/2/ (forked from yours).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was quite simple. Your constructors for File, Claim etc were great except you were never using them. You were pushing raw json into your collections, for example.

```
this.files.push(file2);
```

Should really be

```
this.files.push(new File(file2));
```

You also weren't initializing your objects properly. Here is a fiddle demonstrating how to do it with the mapping plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/a8mZY/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly!  Also I appreciate your demonstrating the use of the mapping plugin.  My end goal was to use that however being new to KO I wanted to start simple and ensure I understood the basics before adding in more layers of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Also, another clean up of your code with manual mapping of your datamodel

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/d64TN/